# Trigger Does not works - Alter table to add a new column before inserting in it

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, alter

I am making a trigger to alter a table that adds a new column to it and inserts the value in it.

My code looks lyk dis:

```sql
 delimiter |

 CREATE TRIGGER addfield AFTER INSERT ON `entity_group_mapping`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     ALTER TABLE user_access ADD NEW.type_name INT(2) NOT NULL;
 END;

 |
 delimiter ;
```

It is giving me an error: `#1103 - Incorrect table name 'NEW'`

Comment: Dynamically changing a table structure is usually wrong. What are you trying to do?

Comment: no this my requirement.. I need to bulid a form in which the no. of fields displayed are dyanamic... So adding a new form element needs to add a new column in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

*There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table...Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes.*

Can you reach these limitations?
Even if you cannot, I'd suggest you to think about design, and add records instead of new fields. Then you could try to PIVOT table - translate rows into fields, there are many pivot examples in the internet and of course in stackoverflow.

Comment: ohk thanx.. fr the PIVOT example.. i aint knew dat.

Answer (score 1):

try this without `NEW.`

```
 ALTER TABLE user_access ADD type_name INT(2) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Mysql. Also you can not use prepare statements inside trigger to form and execute a query dynamically.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is also not allowed inside trigger in MySQL. In Oracle, yes you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE` is not allowed inside trigger in MySql. So In anyways it won't work.

Comment: so any other way to achieve dis?

Comment: As far as I know, If you are using MySQL & you want to alter table on any insert in table 'entity_group_mapping', then you may e able to do that only from your server side code, like you can make one method and call it after insert is done successful in one transaction .

Comment: OK. If you want to from trigger then you can do one thing. Prepare the query string to alter table in trigger & then insert that query string in another table, let's say 'alterQuery' table. Now in you application you can write down the code which will run everyday or at interval of 2-3 hours (whatever time period you want) & will fetch all the queries from 'alterQuery' table, create batch and run them. Thus deleting all successfully ran queries & making 'alterQuery' empty

Comment: But my requirement is bit different. See i have two tables entity_field, entity_data, and i have a form that inserts a new row in **entity_field** and at this point i want to add a new column in table **entity_data**. My requirement is to finally generate a dyanamic form whose form elements depends upon the values entered in **entity_data**.. !!

Comment: Ok. Create a stored procedure to insert a new row in `entity_field`. In that stored procedure you also write down the code to alter table `entity_data` & add new column. Also in stored procedure you can write Dynamic SQL if needed.