# Alter Default with value from other table

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set the DEFAULT for a column with a value from a different table in one query?

I tried variations of

```
ALTER table1 ALTER col1 SET DEFAULT (SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE id=1)
ALTER table1 ALTER col1 SET DEFAULT @val:=SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE id=1
```

and

```
SELECT @var:=col2 FROM table2 WHERE id=1;
ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER col1 SET DEFAULT @var
```

but they all throw errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thnx

Comment: Go for an [`ON BEFORE INSERT` - trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: @Wrikken I've tried that yesterday and it didn't fire. As I understand now from other questions here `ALTER TABLE` isn't allowed in a trigger? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790112/trigger-does-not-works-alter-table-to-add-a-new-column-before-inserting-in-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790112/trigger-does-not-works-alter-table-to-add-a-new-column-before-inserting-in-it)

Comment: You don't want an `ALTER TABLE` in the trigger, you just want to set the _value_ of `col1` to `SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE id=1` if it isn't set or `NULL` in the `INSERT`. Defaults cannot be expressions.

Comment: If that isn't an option BTW, an application level `ALTER TABLE`, when you _know_ you altered `col2` and to what value, is to only other option.

Comment: @Wrikken. The whole thing is about setting the default. Makes life afterwards so much easier ;-)
My question: can I do it in one query? Or do I have to read the value from `col2`, process it in php, and then write the default in `table1`?

Comment: the second one. Which is only reliable if you can guarantee 100% control in your application over `table2 WHERE id=1` (in other words: if you can guarantee that only _your_ application updates the value, and _will_ fire an `ALTER TABLE` query).

Comment: Yup. It's mine and mine alone :-) I like playing around with defaults. It makes it so much easier to insert a new user. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The **DEFAULT** value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column.

With one exception, **the default value must be a constant**; **it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,** for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as **NOW() or CURRENT_DATE.**

The exception is that you can specify **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column**.

refrence
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html